# WebView embedded video play/pause options are not appreared on tap in iOS 8.0

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios8

I had embedded video in webview which is loaded from app bundle but now i am having one issue in iOS 8.0.

I am not able to see video play/pause/stop and zoom options panel when i tap on it. I can make it fullscreen by pinch gesture and able to see option panel in full screen but not able to see it while playing normally.

It seems that uiwebview content is not in center or may be its content size is increased. I tried to found its solution online but couldn't found any solution for that. I tried everything which i found about embedding video in uiwebview but the issues is not resolved yet. I think the playback option is appeared but as content size is increased so i think that playback option is being visible out of bound. This issue only occurs in iOS 8.0 and it works fine in ioS 6.0 & 7.0.

Code which i have done to integrate it:

```
                webviewFrame = CGRectMake(335, 67, 675, 670);
                webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webviewFrame];
                [webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [webview setOpaque:NO];
                webview.delegate=self;
                webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
                [webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
                [webview.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                [webview.layer setCornerRadius:15.0f];
                [webview.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
                [webview.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];

                [self.view addSubview:webview];  
                webview.hidden=NO;
                webview.delegate=self;
                btn_Zoom.hidden=YES;
                btnMail.hidden=YES;

                UIScrollView* sv = (UIScrollView*)[webview.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
                sv.scrollEnabled=NO;
                [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath isDirectory:YES]]];


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
     NSLog(@"finish loading");
    [appDelegate hideIndicator];
     self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width,
                                    webView.frame.size.height);
    webview.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
    [webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = YES;

}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error=%@",error);
    [appDelegate hideIndicator];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width,
                                    webView.frame.size.height);
    webview.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
    [webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = YES;
}
```

Please find me accurate solution of this issue as i am trying to solve it from last 2 days.